# Typescript using enum within an interface

Tags: typescript, enums, interface

I am new to Typescript and I am not sure about the syntax. I tried searching online but didn't find anything helpful.

These are my interfaces and enum definitions.

```
interface Products {
    asian: {[key: string]: string};
    american: {[key: string]: string};
}

enum State {
   NEWYORK = 'nyc',
   BOSTON = 'boston'
}

interface Branch {
   nyc: {
     products: Products;
   };
   boston: {
      products: Products;
   };
}
```

I am not sure how to use the Enum `State` inside `Branch` interface. So that I can use `STATE.NEWYORK` and `STATE.BOSTON` Enums.
Something like this:

```
interface Branch {
   State.NEWYORK: {
     products: Products;
   };
   STATE.BOSTON: {
      products: Products;
   };
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Not sure what you mean .. you can define a field in the interface of type status as you could for any other type

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I updated the question. I am confused with the syntax, I want to use the Enum inside `Branch` or make sure the field is of type `Enum` `nyc: State.NEWYORK`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the syntax for computed properties:

```
interface Branch {
   [State.NEWYORK]: {
     products: Products;
   };
   [State.BOSTON]: {
      products: Products;
   };
}
```

Note though that even though you use the `enum` values, the indexer is still string and the value o of the `enum` is used. So any of these will be valid:

```
let f!: Branch;
f[State.NEWYORK]
f["nyc"]
f.nyc
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Products%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20asian%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20american%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20NEWYORK%20%3D%20'nyc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20BOSTON%20%3D%20'boston'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Branch%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%5BState.NEWYORK%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20products%3A%20Products%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%5BState.BOSTON%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20products%3A%20Products%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20f%3A%20Branch%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%5BState.BOSTON%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09products%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09american%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09asian%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%0D%0A%09%5BState.NEWYORK%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09products%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09american%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09asian%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Af%5BState.NEWYORK%5D)

Comment: Using the above solution, I get a TS1169: A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol. Any tips how to fix this.

Comment: @Aniks What ts version are you using, I don't get this error.

Comment: I am using "typescript": "^2.7.2", I get this in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that is generic and doesn't require maintaining:

```js
enum ApiResponseCode {
    SUCCESS = 1,
    FAIL = 2,
    FILE_MODIFIED = 3
};

interface View {
    Enums: {
        ApiResponseCode: {
            [P in keyof typeof ApiResponseCode]: ApiResponseCode;
        }
    }
};
```